# Why is the iterator method present in both Iterable and Collection interfaces?

Tags: java, collections, iterable

The `Iterable` interface has the method below:

```
 Iterator<T> iterator();
```

The `Collection` interface extends `Iterable`, and it also declares the same method.

I am doubtful what was the need of putting the same method declaration twice while designing Java collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason is Java 5.

`java.util.Collection` with its `iterator()` method and `java.util.Iterator` exist since Java 1.2.

When they wanted to introduce the enhanced for loop in Java 5 (the one `for (String s: ...) {}`, they needed a way to create a `java.util.Iterator` from classes that do not implement `java.util.Collection`. The decision was made to introduce a new interface `java.lang.Iterable` that can be implemented by all classes that want to support the enhanced for loop.

To make the existing `java.util.Collection` and all it's descendent interfaces and classes compatible with the enhanced for loop, they made `java.util.Collection` extend `java.lang.Iterable`.

Therefore both interfaces have a method `iterator()` - `java.util.Collection` because it was the "first born", `java.lang.Iterable` for supporting the enhanced for loop.

Comment: Even so I like the historical reasoning I do not see why *they* not drop the method from `Collection` at the point where "they made java.util.Collection extend java.lang.Iterable"?

Comment: @luk2302 the reason for not removing must have been the backward compatibility of the old java codes which still uses earlier versions.

Comment: Removing it wouldn’t affect normal execution of existing Java code. The only thing that wouldn’t work anymore, would be a subset of Reflection, i.e. `Collection.class.getDeclaredMethod("iterator")`. But why remove it? That would require a RFE explaining why to remove it, a developer to make the change, and another developer(s) supervising it and justify why this change doesn’t break anything (or why this minor Reflection issue is negligible).

Answer (score 5):

One possible reason may be the added javadoc making clear what the method is doing. For `Collection` it is:

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection.  There are no
 * guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned
 * (unless this collection is an instance of some class that provides a
 * guarantee).
 *
 * @return an <tt>Iterator</tt> over the elements in this collection
 */
```

while for `Iterable` it "only" is:

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over elements of type {@code T}.
 *
 * @return an Iterator.
 */
```

Answer (score 4):

Redefining interface methods is a common practice the allows the sub-interface to refine the contract defined by the super-interface.

`Iterable`'s `iterator()` returns an iterator over elements of some type.

`Collection`'s `iterator()` returns an iterator over the elements of the `Collection`, without guaranteeing order.

`List`'s `iterator()` returns an iterator over the elements of the `List` in proper sequence.

This means that if you implement the `iterator()` method of some class that implements `Collection`, you should follow the contract of `Collection`'s `iterator()`, which is more specific than `Iterable`'s `iterator()` contract. If your class also implements `List`, you should follow the even more specific contract of `List`'s `iterator()`.