# the Collection extends Iterable, but why Collection declare Iterable Function (same as Iterable)

Tags: java, collections

my java version is "1.8.0_192"

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection.  There are no
 * guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned
 * (unless this collection is an instance of some class that provides a
 * guarantee).
 *
 * @return an <tt>Iterator</tt> over the elements in this collection
 */
Iterator<E> iterator();
```

this is Collection interface.

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over elements of type {@code T}.
 *
 * @return an Iterator.
 */
Iterator<T> iterator();
```

this is Iterable interface.

Comment: And [Why is the iterator method present in both Iterable and Collection interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232366/why-is-the-iterator-method-present-in-both-iterable-and-collection-interfaces?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @Slaw Yes, that one is better, as its answers address the refining of the method’s contract.

Comment: @VGR Couldn't decide which one to actually cast my vote with, so I went with the one that wasn't itself a duplicate and just linked the other. Was sort of hoping a gold badge might come along and add it to the duplicate list—if that's possible when they weren't involved in the initial close (don't know, I don't have a gold badge in any tag).

Answer (score 0):

There is really no reason to have both.  If you look at the `since` section for `Collection`, you will see it was added in 1.2 while `Iterable` was added in 1.5, so it seems to be "historical".

We would have to ask the actual authors why the redundant declaration was not removed.  With that said, there is no negative impact with having it in both places.

And no, there is no special meaning in having the `iterator` method on both.